# UIView: Autoresize all but one subview - iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, autoresize

I have enabled *Autoresize Subviews* in the superview via interface builder. Is there any way to programmatically disable the autoresizing of ONE subview view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you really are using autoresizing, not autolayout.

Set that subview's `autoresizingMask` to `UIViewAutoresizingNone` to make its parent ignore it during autoresizing.